# Is it possible to do a MySQL with IF EXISTS query with two conditions

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE col=val)
    INSERT ......
ELSE
    UPDATE ......
```

I know that you are able to do this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE col=val)
    INSERT ......
```

But I'm not sure if you can do an else along with that.

What would fastest way to do the first query?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. One way to do this is by using a procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$  

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `YOUR-PROCEDURE`$$  

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `YOUR-PROCEDURE`()  
BEGIN  
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE col=val)
THEN      
   BEGIN      
     UPDATE table SET ..;  
   END;      
ELSE      
   BEGIN      
     INSERT INTO table ..;  
   END;      
END IF;     
  END$$  

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
insert into table1 (col1,col2) values(1,2) 
on duplicate key update col2=3, col1=4
```

See [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for more information.